# Sort multiple NSArray objects with the same reordering

Tags: ios, sqlite, sorting, nsarray

I have several `NSArray` objects that, effectively, represent the contents of what on might consider a database table.  I would like to sort one of them and have all of the others get sorted in the same order.

An example of this would be to have `NSArray` objects for "name", "address" and "phone_number" and sort them all by name.

The current approach is a custom shell sort routine that only runs comparisons on "name" but moves data around on all affected arrays.  This works and it is relatively clean.  Of course, you take a hit due to the overhead of `NSObjects` **vs** C arrays.

Is there a faster, cleaner, more "iOS"  way to do this?

Drop it all into an SQLite table and do it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clean way is to store the data in a single `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects. Then you can sort the array like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]; 
NSArray *sortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortName]]
```

The only other way I can think of is:

- Create an index, i.e. an array containing the numbers 0, 1, ..., N-1.
- Sort the index according to the contents of the `name` array.
- For each array, create a sorted array based on the original array and the sorted index.

Comment: I ended up doing it inside the shell sort routine because I had several parallel arrays to do and it felt cleaner.  Your answer is good, so I accepted it.